# How can I chain multiple calls to `into()`?

Tags: rust

In one of my Rust projects, I have a multi-level hierarchy of enums. Here's a simplified version ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0cfaadf20120ff1015ab5ece62e57ab3)):

```
enum Child {
    ChildA,
    ChildB,
}

enum Parent {
    ParentA(Child),
    ParentB,
}

enum GrandParent {
    GrandParentA(Parent),
    GrandParentB,
}
```

For convenience, I have implemented converters between each level and the level above it:

```
impl From<Child> for Parent {
    fn from(c: Child) -> Self {
        Parent::ParentA(c)
    }
}

impl From<Parent> for GrandParent {
    fn from(p: Parent) -> Self {
        GrandParent::GrandParentA(p)
    }
}
```

If I want to convert from a `Child` to a `Parent` I can now do

```
let c: Child = Child::ChildA;
let p: Parent = c.into();
```

But if I want to convert from a `Child` to a `Grandparent`, I can't seem to chain multiple calls to `into()`:

```
let c: Child = Child::ChildA;
let gp: GrandParent = c.into().into();

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:30:29
   |
30 |     let gp: GrandParent = c.into().into();
   |                           --^^^^--
   |                           | |
   |                           | cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the trait `Into`
   |                           this method call resolves to `T`
   |
   = note: type must be known at this point
```

I tried specifying the type using a turbofish, but that doesn't work either:

```
    let c = Child::ChildA;
    let gp: GrandParent = c.into::<Parent>().into();

error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 0, found 1
  --> src/main.rs:31:36
   |
31 |     let gp: GrandParent = c.into::<Parent>().into();
   |                                    ^^^^^^ unexpected type argument
```

What's the correct way to chain these calls to `into()`?

Comment: You are consuming the original struct when converting (which might be what you want, but I assume you have specific methods for each). How do you feel about `impl AsRef<Child> for Parent` and `impl AsRef<Parent> for Child`?

Comment: For this application, I do want to consume the `Child` struct (this conversion is always the last time the `Child` struct is used), but `AsRef` is also a valuable tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```rust
let c: Child = Child::ChildA;
let gp: GrandParent = Into::<Parent>::into(c).into();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want this to compile, use `Into::<TypeToConvertTo>::into(src)`, but I would suggest looking into the problem and whether or not chained calls to `into()` is actually what you want (hint: it's most likely not)

Comment: Could you give more information about why I "most likely" would not want to do this?

Comment: @greg because then you can't call any methods on your original data. I assume child and parent have different behaviors, and it would potentially be better to borrow the others behavior instead of throwing away one behavior for the other. This obviously depends on how the rest of your code is structured.